# Why am I Facing with this problem when run symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, composer-php

I want to learn PHP language and I think Symfony framework is a good start in this direction. First of all I installed XAMPP, composer and at the end Symfony. When I tried to create a new Symfony project I have an error which I really don't understand. I want to specify that I switched the macOS because there I faced a problem as well and gave up. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

```
/c/Program Files/Symfony/symfony: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/c/Program Files/Symfony/symfony: line 1: `<html><body>You are being <a href="https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/160942974/1d15b800-fbf6-11e9-9759-6bb82e459816?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F2019111'
```

Comment: When illustrating a problem in console output, please paste that information as text, not an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: No, this is out of context. Read it before publish it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look like broken files. Try download symfony again.

Comment: I tried this 5 ties in a row.

Comment: I had reinstalled the windows and all that programs and It now works for some reason, I will try to identify the problem and mark your answer as the correct one. Thank you!